# Is the act of moving, eating, doing, and living craving itself?

Tags: meditation, vipassana

I've been practicing Vipassana and reading "The Art of Living" by S.N Goenka.

My questions is, I have obligations. When I wake up in the morning I have a thought to go to the bathroom and brush my teeth. Then I follow with that thought and perform the actions. How is this different from me craving that action? If I simply observe the thought of brushing my teeth, and mentally note "thoughts", it will help the thought fade but now I do not accomplish anything in my life. How do I know what thoughts must be left to "fade" and what thoughts I must act on? If I'm acting on a thought, isn't that due to aversion/craving?

Where do you draw the line?

Comment: Seems like essentially the same question as [this one](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/31408/dukha-vs-legitimate-need)?

Comment: That's right. It's a good question but it was asked and answered before

Comment: Closing as dupe - if you read the answers and still have a (new, different) question, you can edit this one and I will reopen.

Comment: This might be different if it were asking for, specifically Goenka's doctrine (about meditation). Or if answers should focus on "craving versus wholesome desire" instead of "attachment versus legitimate need".